# Attempting to pass char array to function

Tags: c

I'm attempting to pass a `char` array to a function I'm creating so I can see if two car IDs are equal. The function I'm creating is called `mpg` which accepts a `char *id`. If the ID passed to the function equals any car's ID, it prints out a 1. The ID is a string also by the way. I'm very new to programming in C, so any help would be nice. Any questions please ask.

The car information columns are number, ID, odometer, gallons respectively.

**CAR INFORMATION**

```
0 987654 201200 4.000000
1 red 89114 0.000000
2 red 89712 13.500000
3 red 90229 15.300000
4 987654 201001 0.000000
5 987654 201111 5.200000
6 987654 201612 25.299999
7 red 89300 7.100000
8 green 16 0.000000
9 green 216 20.000000
10 green 518 61.000000
11 green 879 50.000000
```

**CODE**

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define numberOfRecords 12

struct record
{
    char *id;
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record gasRecord;

gasRecord gasDataArray[numberOfRecords];

void mpg(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fileInput;
    float gallons;
    int   element, odometer;
    char  id[10];
    char  test[10] = {"987654"};

    fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
    if (fileInput == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open `gasData.txt'\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(element = 0; element < numberOfRecords; element++)
    {
        if(feof(fileInput))
        {
            printf("end-of-file detected on file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fscanf(fileInput, "%s %d %f", id, &odometer, &gallons) == 3)
        {
            gasDataArray[element].id = malloc (strlen(id)+1);
            strcpy(gasDataArray[element].id, id);
            gasDataArray[element].odometer = odometer;
            gasDataArray[element].gallons = gallons;

            printf("Record #: %d id = %s, odometer = %d, gallons = %f\n",
                   element, gasDataArray[element].id, gasDataArray[element].odometer, gasDataArray[element].gallons);
        }
    }

    printf("Test ID = %s\n", test);

    mpg(test);

    return 0;
}

void mpg(char *id)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++)
    {

        if (gasDataArray[i].id == id)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED CODE**

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define numberOfRecords 12

struct record
{
    char *id;
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record gasRecord;

gasRecord gasDataArray[numberOfRecords];

void mpg(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fileInput;
    float gallons;
    int   element, odometer;
    char  id[10];
    char  test[10] = {"red"};

    fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
    if (fileInput == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open `gasData.txt'\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(element = 0; element < numberOfRecords; element++)
    {
        if(feof(fileInput))
        {
            printf("end-of-file detected on file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fscanf(fileInput, "%s %d %f", id, &odometer, &gallons) == 3)
        {
            gasDataArray[element].id = malloc (strlen(id)+1);
            strcpy(gasDataArray[element].id, id);
            gasDataArray[element].odometer = odometer;
            gasDataArray[element].gallons = gallons;

            printf("Record #: %d id = %s, odometer = %d, gallons = %f\n",
                   element, gasDataArray[element].id, gasDataArray[element].odometer, gasDataArray[element].gallons);
        }
    }

    printf("Test ID = %s\n", test);

    mpg(test);

    return 0;
}

void mpg(char *id)
{
    int i, minMile = 0, maxMile = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++)
    {

        if (strcmp(id, gasDataArray[i].id))
        {
            printf("1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your format string and arguments do you account for the leading line number present in your input data?

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==` in C.

Comment: Are you talking about the Car number? If so, I just use the count of the loop for the 0, 1, 2, ..., 11.

Comment: No I mean the `mpg` function with `if (gasDataArray[i].id == id)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm stupid, I just used strcmp and it worked perfectly. I'm just so use to C++ that this kind of programming is new to me. Thanks alain

Comment: Strcmp returns 0 if the strings match. So it's usual to check the return value == 0 to determine if the string matches.

Comment: As a general rule, you'll get the best answers if you don't post your entire program, but instead a minimal fragment which displays the problem, or the behaviour you don't understand.  As a side-effect, the effort of constructing that minimal fragment can very often help you realise precisely what it is you're having difficulty with, and can even help you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings with `==` in C. –  alain

I just used strcmp and it worked perfectly. I'm just so use to C++ that this kind of programming is new to me. Thanks alain –  Johnny Andrea